# Laravel 5 Pass data from two tables to the view

Tags: php, laravel-5

I'm using Laravel to create a CRUD application but I'm a little stuck. What I want to do is to display the coresponding Category from 'categories' table for each Product from the 'products' table. I tried to squeeze the two tables in one view and create a @foreach within the @foreach but that only listed all the categories instead of assigning the coresponding category based on the category_id from the products table.

Controller

```
$products = products::all();
$categories = categories::all();

return View::make('products.index')->with('products', $products)->with('categories', $categories);
```

View

```
@foreach($products as $key => $value)
    <tr>
        <td>{!! $value->id !!}</td>
        <td>{!! $value->product_name !!}</td>
        @foreach($categories as $key2 => $value2)
            <td>{!! $value2->category !!}</td>
        @endforeach
        <td>{!! $value->product_price !!}</td>
        <td>{!! $value->updated_at !!}</td>
        <td>
@endforeach
```

products table

```
    Schema::create('products', function($table)
    {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('category_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
        $table->string('product_name', 255)->unique();
        $table->decimal('product_price', 10, 4);
        $table->dateTime('updated_at')->default(DB::raw('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'));
    });

    Schema::table('products', function($table) {
        $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('categories');
    });
```

categories table

```
    Schema::create('categories', function($table)
    {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('category', 255)->unique();
        $table->dateTime('updated_at')->default(DB::raw('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'));
    });
```

Comment: When you do `$products = products::all();` and `$categories = categories::all();`, there is nothing that will automatically associate the two resulting collections. This is why you get the entire list of categories from your inner loop.

Comment: Is there a way in Laravel to asociate each product to the coresponding category ? I searched for an answer and what and I found a solution by creatin a pivot table. But I think maybe there is an easier method of doing this.

Comment: Yes, I think there is an easier method. First, does a product have potentially multiple categories, or just one?

Comment: Each product has just one category.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [join](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/queries#joins) to get the category for each product in one query.

```
$products = DB::table('products')
    ->join('categories', 'products.category_id', '=', 'categories.id')->get();
```

If each product has only one category, then your view can be simplified.

```
@foreach($products as $key => $value)
    <tr>
        <td>{!! $value->id !!}</td>
        <td>{!! $value->product_name !!}</td>
        <td>{!! $value->category !!}</td>
        <td>{!! $value->product_price !!}</td>
        <td>{!! $value->updated_at !!}</td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

Comment: It's working. I never thought about using join table. I should look more into joins. Thank you.